# ROUTE 53 domain redirect to ip of instance inestead to keep the domain url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I need help setting up ROUTE 53,

I created a hosted zone, pointed the dns and everything works normally So when I access [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) it loads the site but redirected to the ip of my instance eg http://xx.xxxx.xxxx.xx .

I configured an elastic IP for my instance...

**My created records:**

- A - *mydomain.com
- A - [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- A -  mydomain.com
- NS - dns nameserves
- SOA - aws host master

What could I be missing to avoid this redirection from the domain to the ip? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Route53 is a DNS service. It is only used for DNS name resolution. Route53 does not perform redirects.

Redirects are part of the HTTP protocol. Only an HTTP web server would return a redirect.

Whatever software you have running on your instance has not been configured to be aware of the domain name it is serving, so it is defaulting to the IP address of the server.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. But thats exacly what Im tring to figure out. Amazon documentation dont make any suggestion about an addtional configuration on apache config.

Comment: So you're using Apache as your web server software? That means this is really an Apache question. Apache web server on Amazon isn't any different than Apache web server anywhere else. You are looking in the wrong place if you are expecting Amazon to give you an Apache config. You need to search for this problem without the focus on AWS. It looks like you need to configure the `ServerName` property in your Apache config.